# Правильность фразы "как по мне, так..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

А подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли грамотным выражение "Как по мне, так..."?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5) устойчивое сочетание "как по мне" отмечено как просторечное и приведены цитаты с употреблением, взятые из Нацкорпуса. На мой взгляд, это выражение звучит не хуже чем просто "по мне" (в Викисловаре оно помечено как разговорное и приведена цитата из Ахматовой) или повсеместно используемое в хорошей художественной литературе "что до меня".

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что тут не совсем правильно вопрос поставлен. Рассматриваемую конструкцию нельзя рассматривать как нечто неделимое, она состоит из двух "как... так..." (как на охоту ехать - так собак кормить) и "по мне", которое фиксируется с незапамятных времен как вполне литературное, ну разве что разговорное.

Так проблема, если она есть, только в сочетаемости этих конструкций. И вот тут действительно есть некоторое сомнение, семантика союза "как... так..." не совсем подходит для подобного использования, он не предназначен для выражения мнения, источника информации.

Но это не "абсолютная безграмотность", как утверждает один автор. Скорее всего этот вариант надо признать обычным просторечием, постепенно поднимающимся до разговорной нормы.

Comment: Согласен с Вашими выводами и поддерживаю ответ. Но хочу поинтересоваться Вашим мнением по поводу "сочетаемости конструкций": эта сочетаемость в выражении "как по мне, так" хуже, чем в выражении "что до меня, так"?

Comment: @grizzly Думаю, в целом - одинаково хорошо и плохо. Но вариант "что до меня, так" хуже тем, что в нем еще и сомнительная конструкция союза "что..., так..." Нет такого союза в литературном языке, надо бы "что до меня, то" - и вот этой фразе я бы предоставил некоторые права "разговорного гражданства". Но в неё, правда, тоже не всякую мысль упакуешь.

Comment: Спасибо. А фраза "что до меня, то" имеет вполне литературный статус, имхо, — слишком часто она встречается в воспоминаниях и размышлениях классиков, начиная с Ф.М. Достоевского.

Answer (score 1):

"Грамотным" это выражение является не всегда, а только в определенных ситуациях. **Это просторечие,  молодежный сленг** со значением "по-моему, с моей точки зрения". Чтобы не использовать в разговорной речи такие "книжные слова", применяют это  выражение.

**"Как по мне, так...."** можно встретить на форумах, где разговаривают между собой вполне образованные люди на различные темы. В художественных произведениях это речь персонажей  в разговорных ситуациях.

В то же время это выражение будет неуместным **в письменных текстах или при общении с мало знакомыми людьми**. Иначе говоря, оно применяется **в "своей компании".**

**Примеры:**

**Как по мне, то** книг было многовато. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

**Как по мне, так** тут даже вопроса нет. [коллективный. Форум: Мобилография. Искусство или художественный фаст фуд? (2008)]

Графика у обеих игр, **как по мне**, совершенно приемлемая. [Автогонки-1 (форум) (2005)]

Answer (score 0):

можно, но не нужно. можно заменить "по моему мнению"

Answer (score -2):

Это абсолютно безграмотно. Вероятно, является калькой английского "As for me". Говорить так не следует. Лучше использовать фразы "я считаю", "я думаю". Книжными они не являются, вопреки замечаниям прошлого комментатора.

Comment: Насчет "абсолюно безграмотно". Хотелось бы более аргументированного обоснования столь категорического утверждения.

Comment: Я уже объяснил.Это калька с английского.Есть нормальные выражения,заменяющие данное.Если хотите показать низкий уровень своего развития-говорите "как по мне".А ещё "типа"(после каждого слова),"то  что","чо" и так далее.

Comment: Вообще,если у человека нет интуиции и он не понимает,что говорить "как по мне"-неграмотно,то мне сложно ему это объяснить.

Comment: А если человек не понимает, что ссылка на "интуицию" тут прокатит, то мне сложно объяснить, что ответ ответ ваш - абсолютно не в формате ресурса.